# How to run Vite with a different entry point than index.html

Tags: vite

Would like to run vite from the cli and use a different entry point than ./index.html like so:

```
vite -entrypoint ./gallery/slider.html
```

I cannot find a cli option and also no config option that allows a different entry point.

I am concerned about dev serving not about the build phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `vite serve ./gallery/` then just visit localhost:5173/slider.html.

In dev mode you can have as many inputs as you like

Comment: How do you run Vite with a *file* as the entry point? Parcel can simply do `parcel test.html`.